# access child scope of ng-repeat outside ng-repeat loop and two way data bind

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a ng-repeat and inside each repeated li I am trying to put ng-model and later I want two way data binding outside of the ng-repeat. See this below jsbin.

http://jsbin.com/yutinifivi/edit?html,js,output

I know there have been lot of questions answered on ng-model and ng-repeat. But I am unable to find the required solution.

Pls if anybody is patient enough to understand my problem, it would be helpfull in learning angularjs.

Relevant code:

```js
(function(){
  var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
}());

(function(){
  var myCtrl = function($scope){
    $scope.selection_add = {};
    $scope.selection_edit = {};
    $scope.selection_delete ={};
    $scope.categories = [ 
        {"name": "Sport", "id": "50d5ad" } , 
        {"name": "General", "id": "687ffr" },
        {"name": "Activities", "id": "678ffb" },
        {"name": "Regards", "id": "678fff" },
        {"name": "Thanks", "id": "678fer" },
        {"name": "Goes", "id": "678fgf" },
        {"name": "Oppertnities", "id": "674ffr" },
        {"name": "Convince", "id": "654ffr" },
        {"name": "Mopols", "id": "623ffr" } 
    ];
    
    $scope.setCurrentCategory = function setCurrentCategory(category) {
      $scope.currentCategory = category;
    };
  };
  angular.module("myApp")
  .controller("myCtrl", myCtrl);
}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div>
          <table>
              <tr>
                  <th>add</th>
                  <th>edit</th>
                  <th>delete</th>
              </tr>
              <tr ng-repeat="category in categories" ng-click="setCurrentCategory(category)">
                  <td><input id="{{category.id + '_add'}}" ng-model="selection_add[category.id]" type="text">{{category.name}}</td>
                  <td><input id="{{category.id + '_edit'}}" ng-model="selection_edit[category.id]" type="text">{{category.name}}</td>
                  <td><input id="{{category.id + '_delete'}}" ng-model="selection_delete[category.id]" type="text">{{category.name}}</td>
              </tr>
          </table>
    
        <h1>Add for {{currentCategory.name}}</h1>
        <input type="text" ng-model="selection_add[currentCategory.id]">
        <h1>Edit for {{currentCategory.name}}</h1>
        {{selection_edit[currentCategory.id]}}
        <h1>Delete for {{currentCategory.name}}</h1>
        {{selection_delete[currentCategory.id]}}
      </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The way you are passing the value in the from the HTML to the controller is wrong

Comment: I didn't understand, can you please explain? For example, the user adds ??? to the sport category and as a result ??? happens, same for edit and delete.

Answer (score 0):

You use a property in an object as the model for each `input`, and then you try to display the data you've entered. However, when you try to display data, you don't point the model at the property you are changing. You just use the whole object.

To solve that, I've added a click which stores the `currentCategory`, and then display all data according to it - [demo](http://jsbin.com/vijamefavo/1/edit?html,js,output).

Changes to html:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="category in categories" ng-click="setCurrentCategory(category)"> <-- note the ng-click that saves currentCategory -->


    <!-- currentCategory is used to change the model to our currentCategory, and display the category name -->
    <h1>Add for {{currentCategory.name}}</h1>
    <input type="text" ng-model="selection_add[currentCategory.id]">
    <h1>Edit for {{currentCategory.name}}</h1>
    {{selection_edit[currentCategory.id]}}
    <h1>Delete for {{currentCategory.name}}</h1>
    {{selection_delete[currentCategory.id]}}
```

Add this to the controller:

```
$scope.setCurrentCategory = function setCurrentCategory(category) {
  $scope.currentCategory = category;
};
```